# How to find the number of times a specific element is repeated in a column

Tags: r

I am new to R, however, i would like to use R to help me find the number of times that a specific value is repeated in a column? For example, using the following data, how can I find the number of times that the value 23.9 is repeated the column for Distance.?

```
Distance Age Height Coning
1      21.4  18    3.3    Yes
2      13.9  17    3.4    Yes
3      23.9  16    2.9    Yes
4       8.7  18    3.6     No
5     241.8   6    0.7     No
6      44.5  17    1.3    Yes
7      30.0  15    2.5    Yes
8      32.3  16    1.8    Yes
9      31.4  17    5.0     No
10     32.8  13    1.6     No
11     53.3  12    2.0     No
12     54.3   6    0.9     No
13     96.3  11    2.6     No
14    133.6   4    0.6     No
15     32.1  15    2.3     No
16     57.9  12    2.4    Yes
17     30.8  17    1.8     No
18     59.9   7    0.8     No
19     42.7  15    2.0    Yes
20     20.6  18    1.7    Yes
21     62.0   8    1.3     No
22     53.1   7    1.6     No
23     28.9  16    2.2    Yes
24    177.4   5    1.1     No
25     24.8  14    1.5    Yes
26     75.3  14    2.3    Yes
27     51.6   7    1.4     No
28     36.1   9    1.1     No
29    116.1   6    1.1     No
30     28.1  16    2.5    Yes
31      8.7  19    2.2    Yes
32    105.1   6    0.8     No
33     46.0  15    3.0    Yes
34    102.6   7    1.2     No
35     15.8  15    2.2     No
36     60.0   7    1.3     No
37     96.4  13    2.6     No
38     24.2  14    1.7     No
39     14.5  15    2.4     No
40     36.6  14    1.5     No
41     65.7   5    0.6     No
42    116.3   7    1.6     No
43    113.6   8    1.0     No
44     16.7  15    4.3    Yes
45     66.0   7    1.0     No
46     60.7   7    1.0     No
47     90.6   7    0.7     No
48     91.3   7    1.3     No
49     14.4  18    3.1    Yes
50     72.8  14    3.0    Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (with a `data.frame` `df`)

```
sum(df$Distance == 23.9, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Remember R FAQ 7.31 applies when making floating point comparisons http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html

Comment: Agree w/ Spacedman; putting in my plug for `approxeq` in my package `cgwtools` .

Comment: Thank you very much. You have answered my question very well.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for the reminder, then sum(abs(df$Distance - 23.9) < .Machine$double.eps^0.5) should do the tricks

Answer (score 2):

If your data is called `dat`

```
table(dat$Distance) 
#or
library(plyr)
count(dat$Distance) 
#or
xtabs(~dat$Distance) 
#or 
# specifically for 23.9 alone
nrow(dat[dat$Distance %in% 23.9 ,])
```

Comment: `count` is in the `plyr` package, you have to load it first

Comment: @user1317221_G  don't I recognize that avatar from xkcd/1190?  "who" are you over there?  (signed, cellocgw)

Comment: . @CarlWitthoft hey think it might be a double up on the avi's